# Problem after change port proftpd

Tags: ftp

This morning, my ISP has changed the ftp port. Now it is working through 10829.

In port 21, we have a lot of scans, and the last week, the server had a brute force attack.

In the ptoftpd.log, the connection is successful, but in the ftp client, the connection doesn´t work

I have this error in the ftp:

```
Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Reply:          220 ProFTPD 1.3.1 Server () [::ffff:X.X.X.X]
Command:    USER xxxxxx
Reply:          331 Password required for efetepero
Command:    PASS ******************
Reply:      230 User efetepero logged in
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Reply:          200 UTF8 set to on
Status:     Conectado
Status:         Recuperando el listado del directorio...
Command:    PWD
Reply:          257 "/home/data" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Reply:          200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Reply:      227 Entering Passive Mode (X,X,X,X,203,146).
Command:    LIST
Error:  Connect time out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

When the port 21 was configured, the ftp worked without problems.

In the connection with notepad++ by ftp, I list the directory, but i don´t see any file

I see that the ftp client work in the pasive mode,but in the protpd.conf doesn´t configure this opcion( i only change tie port)

Best regard

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your ISP has also filtered the TCP ports for passive connections.

They should limit the passive port range with the conf option

```
PassivePorts            60000 60199
```

That'll limit passive ports to 60000 to 60199

Then once the passive ports are limited just open the ports on the firewall corresponding to that range